# How can I read the last change even if the program is closed and opened in the differences in the flutter program?

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I am developing a project in flutter. this project works with api. I offer the option to change the api url from within the program. When the user makes changes in the program, even if the program is opened and closed, I want to read the last change.

I'm new to flutter so I don't know. I am asking this question for information. For example, I gave the value x to the api variable. Then I gave the y value instead of the x value in the program. Now I want to read every xaman y variable when the program is closed and opened. What is my way to do this?

`If I give an example from C#, properties settings file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [shared_preferences package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) for this.

Slightly shortened example from their own page:

Setting the value:

```
// Obtain shared preferences.
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

// Save an String value to 'action' key.
await prefs.setString('url', 'https://your.api.example.com');
```

Reading the value later or after a app restart:

```
// Obtain shared preferences.
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

final String? url = prefs.getString('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) in flutter, Hive greatly outperforms SQLite and SharedPreferences when it comes to writing or deleting.

code example

```
var box = Hive.box('myBox');

box.put('urlName', 'url');

var name = box.get('urlName');

print('URL: $urlName');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in device local storage.There are a lot of methods, you can achieve this thing. Here are couple of most use options you can consider.

1. Use sharedPreference to store data.
   [Shared Preference Package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)
2. If you are using getx state management, you can use getstorage.
3. [Getx Package Link](https://pub.dev/packages/get)